# OS X keys conflicting with emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

I've been trying to optimise my OS X workflow and have swapped `Command-Tab` with `Control-F4`. This allows me to only switching to apps within the current space with `Command-Tab` rather than switching apps globally.

The issue is that emacs conflicts with this and doesn't allow OS X to switch app, I just get the warning `<C-f4> is undefined`.

My question is, how do I configure emacs so that it ignores keys and allows the OS to handle them instead?

**Edit:**
I used [karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to rebind the system keys.

Comment: It is the other way around.  If keys are set at the system level, then Emacs never sees them.  You will need to look for a way to better configure your keys at the system level so that Emacs does not see them -- instead of trying to let the keyboard shortcut flow through Emacs like an open door (in one ear and out the other).  You don't say in the question how it is that you swapped keys, whether you are using some third party app or whether you opened up keyboard shortcuts in system preferences, so there is insufficient information for anyone to really help here.

Comment: For example, if you set a keyboard shortcut at the system level as OSX was designed -- i.e., by opening up System Preferences, then selecting Keyboard, then selecting Keyboard Shortcuts, and setting the shortcut -- then, Emacs will never see it.  To illustrate this point, I just opened up Keyboard Shortcuts in System Preferences and set Control-F4 to "Save picture of selected area as a file."  Then, I went over to Emacs and tried pressing Control-F4 and Emacs never sees it because OSX immediately takes control and lets me "Save picture of selected area as a file."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my post with the relevant software.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question.  Emacs cannot solve this problem, and this is not technically speaking a programming question that falls within the parameters of questions generally appearing in the Emacs tag of stackoverflow.com.  You may wish to consider contacting the authors of **Karabiner** to let them know it is not properly intercepting `Control-F4` at the system level and said keyboard shortcut is erroneously being registered by other applications (such as Emacs).

Comment: If you wish to create an Emacs workaround of the **Karabiner** *bug* discussed in the preceding comment, you can write an *applescript* to do whatever you want and activate it within Emacs like the following example that opens Safari:  `(define-key global-map [C-f4] (lambda () (interactive) (do-applescript "tell application \"Safari\" to activate")))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll contact the Karabiner authors and see what they say. If there's a workaround, I'll post it as an answer.